# text-overflow: ellipsis is not working to pre tag or white-space pre text all lines in IE & Edge

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

In IE, `text-overflow: ellipsis` is not working for `<pre>` tag text and `white-space: pre` text. Only for the first line, it is working fine and for the rest of the lines, it is not working in the Chrome browser, it is working fine for all the browsers.

[image]

```css
.myText {
  white-space: pre;
  color: blue;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Angular Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<div >

<div class="container">
  <h1>Pre Tag or Pre Text with Textoverlow ellipsis:</h1>
<div style="WIDTH: 100PX;">
<div class="myText">print "Hello world, how are you doing today? 
Is this getting cut off yet?
Hello world, how are you doing today? </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made a test with ellipsis in IE and Edge. I find that you have to add each line in a  separate tag to get effect of ellipsis in each line. If you have multiple lines in a single div than it will only add ellipsis effect on the last line. I did not get any solution or work around with only using CSS or JQuery. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Add `span` to every single new line.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3Lda25n/2/)

```css
.myText span {
  white-space: pre;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h1>Pre Tag or Pre Text with Textoverlow ellipsis:</h1>
  <div style="WIDTH: 100PX;">
    <div class="myText">
      <span>print "Hello world, how are you doing today?</span>
      <span>Is this getting cut off yet?</span>
      <span>Hello world, how are you doing today?</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The content will come from back-end not static. And we should not use <span> or <br/> tags, we have issues with special characters like ge & le (> <). If we use html tags in the content we need to add data-html=true, hence it creates issues with < and > tags.

Comment: can anyone suggest with pure css or Jquery if we can achieve this.

Comment: @BaluP your question is not clear! You have only mentioned the HTML and CSS.

Comment: sorry for confusion. i just notify the issue in the front-end view. It's not to possible to do any changes in the back-end. so i don't explain those.